# How to show every second R ggplot2 x-axis label value?

Tags: r, ggplot2, debian, axis-labels

I want to show every second of x-axis label list in the presentation.
Simplified code example in the following and its output in Fig. 1 where four Dates shown but #2 and #4 should be skipped.

```
# https://stackoverflow.com/a/6638722/54964
require(ggplot2)
my.dates = as.Date(c("2011-07-22","2011-07-23",
                     "2011-07-24","2011-07-28","2011-07-29"))
my.vals  = c(5,6,8,7,3)
my.data <- data.frame(date =my.dates, vals = my.vals)
plot(my.dates, my.vals)
p <- ggplot(data = my.data, aes(date,vals))+ geom_line(size = 1.5)
```

Expected output: skip dates second and fourth.

### Actual code

Actual code where due to `rev(Vars)` logic, I cannot apply `as.Date` to the values in each category; the variable `molten` has a column `Dates`

```
p <- ggplot(molten, aes(x = rev(Vars), y = value)) + 
    geom_bar(aes(fill=variable), stat = "identity", position="dodge") + 
    facet_wrap( ~ variable, scales="free") +
    scale_x_discrete("Column name dates", labels = rev(Dates))
```

Expected output: skip #2,#4, ... values in each category. 
I thought here changing `scale_x_discrete` to `scale_x_continuous` and having a break sequence `breaks = seq(1,length(Dates),2))` in `scale_x_continuous` but it fails because of the following error.

```
Error: `breaks` and `labels` must have the same length
```

### Proposal based Juan's comments

Code

```
ggplot(data = my.data, aes(as.numeric(date), vals)) + 
  geom_line(size = 1.5) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = pretty(as.numeric(rev(my.data$date)), n = 5))
```

Output

```
Error: Discrete value supplied to continuous scale
```

### Testing EricWatt's proposal application into Actual code

Code proposal

```
p <- ggplot(molten, aes(x = rev(Vars), y = value)) + 
    geom_bar(aes(fill=variable), stat = "identity", position="dodge") + 
    facet_wrap( ~ variable, scales="free") +
    scale_x_discrete("My dates", breaks = Dates[seq(1, length(Dates), by = 2)], labels = rev(Dates))
```

Output

```
Error: `breaks` and `labels` must have the same length
```

If you have `scale_x_discrete("My dates", breaks = Dates[seq(1, length(Dates), by = 2)])`, you get x-axis without any labels so blank.

Fig. 1 Output of the simplified code example, 
Fig. 2 Output of EricWatt's first proposal

[image]
[image]

OS: Debian 9
R: 3.4.0

Comment: Try `scale_x_continuous(breaks=pretty(rev(Vars), length(Vars)/2))`

Comment: @juan I get `Error in rev(Vars) : object 'Vars' not found` with your proposal.

Comment: Sorry about that! This won't work for dates unless you pass `as.Date`, which is overly complicated. @EricWatt's answer is what you should use.

Comment: per linked answer, it works if you call `as.numeric`, eg, `ggplot(data=my.data, aes(as.numeric(date), vals)) + geom_line() + scale_x_continuous(breaks=pretty(as.numeric(rev(my.data$date))))`, but then you probably want to add labels, and I find this is overly complicated!

Comment: Sorry, you need to specify the number of breaks in `pretty`, so add `pretty(..., n=4)`.

Comment: @juan Please, see the body for the output. What do you think?

Comment: I couldn't reproduce your error. Copied your code and [it works for me](http://imgur.com/a/6EE3O).

Comment: [Here it is](http://imgur.com/a/iZlNv) with labels: `ggplot(data=my.data, aes(as.numeric(date), vals)) + geom_line(size=1.5) + scale_x_continuous(breaks=pretty(as.numeric(rev(my.data$date)), n=4), labels=format(rev(my.data$date), format="%m/%d/%y"))`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This works with your simplified example. Without your `molten` data.frame it's hard to check it against your more complicated plot.

```
ggplot(data = my.data, aes(date, vals)) + 
  geom_line(size = 1.5) +
  scale_x_date(breaks = my.data$date[seq(1, length(my.data$date), by = 2)])
```

Basically, use `scale_x_date` which will likely handle any strange date to numeric conversions for you.

Comment: It has a tick mark and label for dates 1, 3, and 5, skipping 2 and 4. Is there something else you expected?

Comment: Your dates are `c("2011-07-22","2011-07-23", "2011-07-24","2011-07-28","2011-07-29")`. The dates for #2 and #4 are `"2011-07-23"` and `"2011-07-28"`. These are the dates you want to skip labels on the x axis. The dates you want shown are `"2011-07-22"`, `"2011-07-24"`, and `"2011-07-29"`. The output in the image you provided based on my code shows exactly these dates. I'm not understanding what output you would like, but this provides exactly what you've described in the question.

Comment: I used `scale_x_date` not `scale_x_discrete`. Also try leaving off the `labels` parameter.

Comment: I can't test your Actual Code because I don't have `molten` data. If the reproducible example doesn't demonstrate the problem you're having, it's not a good reproducible example. Maybe modify the simplified example so that it represents what you're trying to do?

Comment: I found a solution based on the other thread actual data and your answer. I added it here as a wiki answer.

Answer (score 4):

My solution eventually on the actual code motivated by the other linked thread and EricWatt's answer

```
# Test data of actual data here # https://stackoverflow.com/q/45130082/54964

ggplot(data = molten, aes(x = as.Date(Time.data, format = "%d.%m.%Y"), y = value)) + 
  geom_bar(aes(fill = variable), stat = "identity", position = "dodge") +
  facet_wrap( ~ variable, scales="free") +
  theme_bw() + # has to be before axis text manipulations because disables their effect otherwise
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust=1), 
        text = element_text(size=10)) +
  scale_x_date(date_breaks = "2 days", date_labels = "%d.%m.%Y")
```

Comment: I like this answer better because 'date_breaks' gives an easier way to manipulate the date interval and including 'date_labels' was very useful with the formatting.